# how to use "addEventListener" for multiple objects

Tags: javascript, dom, addeventlistener

Every time I try to use "addEventListener" to select all 3 "li" forming an "ul" I get a message saying that my variable is not a function.

```
var lis = document.querySelectorAll("li");
lis.addEventListener
//i get 
lis.addEventListener is not a function
```

However, if I try to select each "li" individually it works fine. 
Could you please help with this problem. Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

**querySelectorAll** saves all the li elements into array. so you'll have to loop through each and every 'li' to add event listener.

```
var lis = document.querySelectorAll('li');

lis.forEach(function(li) {
  li.addEventListener('click', function() {
    //handle event here
  })
})
```

Comment: I followed your advice and that's what i did:




var lis = document.getElementsByTagName("li")

lis.forEach(function(li) {
  li.addEventListener("click", function() {
    li.style.color = "red"
  })
})

TypeError: lis.forEach is not a function




As you can see it's the same result as before..

Comment: This way it works:
var x = document.querySelectorAll("li");

for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  x[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.style.color = "red"
  })
}

Comment: Don't use getElementsByTagName instead use querySeletectorAll(),  it will return a nodelist that can be iterable with foreach.

Comment: getElementsByTagName() returns a HTML collection object so you can't use forEach, you can use for loop like, @citizen3 's for loop.

Comment: or convert the nodelist to an array and use it. Or as @mahmud said you can use querySelectorAll() and loop through the nodelist.

Answer (score 0):

use [querySelectorAll](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselectorall.asp)() instead

```
const lists = document.querySelectorAll('li');

lists.forEach((list) => {
  list.addEventListener('click', () => {
    // work here
  })
})
```